# Not output the same word twice in Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm fairly new to Python and I have this code that imports a csv file, stems it, and prints each word of the file into its own row in a new csv file. For example:

csv file:

```
The dog is black and has a black collar
```

output csv file:

```
The
dog
is
black
and
has
a
black
collar
```

However, I want the output to NOT print the same word twice if it is in the SAME ROW. For example:

desired output csv file:

```
The
dog
is
black
and
has
a
collar
```

Notice how the word "black" was not printed twice? That's what I want. If anyone could help me out with that, that'd be great. Like I said, I'm still new to Python to I'm figuring it out. Thanks in advance!

```
for row in file1:
    row = row.strip()
    row = row.lower()

    for stopword in internal_stop_words:
        if stopword in row:
            row = row.replace(stopword," ")

    for word in row.split():
        writer.writerow([word])
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't need print in order of first showing in the text, then you can try set()

```
>>> s = 'The dog is black and has a black collar'
>>> s.split()
['The', 'dog', 'is', 'black', 'and', 'has', 'a', 'black', 'collar']
>>> set(s.split())
{'is', 'has', 'black', 'and', 'dog', 'collar', 'a', 'The'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try accumulating the words you've seen already in a `set`, then only output words that aren't in the set:

```
# before you process the file
seen_words = set()

# ... later, in the loop...
for word in row.split():
  if word not in seen_words:
    writer.writerow([word])
    seen_words.add(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up solving my own question! Thanks for the suggestions though. Here's what I did:

```
for row in file1:
    row = row.strip()
    row = row.lower()

    for stopword in internal_stop_words:
        if stopword in row:
            row = row.replace(stopword," ")

    mylist = row.split()
    newlist = []
    for word in mylist:
        if not word in newlist:
            newlist.append(word)
            writer.writerow([word])
```